# vsprintf on OS X: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I've discovered weird behavior of vsprintf on OSX.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#if defined(WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#define VSNPRINTF _vsnprintf
#elif defined(LINUX) || defined (DARWIN)
#define VSNPRINTF vsnprintf
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

char *f(const char *fmt, ...)
{
 char *out = NULL;
 const int step = 32;
 int n = -1, lout = step;
 va_list arg;

 if(fmt!=NULL)
 {
  va_start(arg, fmt);
  do
  {
   if(!out)
   {
    free(out);
    out = NULL;
   }
   out = (char*)malloc(lout + 1);
   if(!out) break;
   memset(out, 0, lout + 1);   

   n = VSNPRINTF(out, lout, fmt, arg);
   if(n == -1 || n + 1 > lout)
   {
    lout += step;
    n = -1;
   }
  }while(n == -1);
  va_end(arg);
 }

 return out;
}

int main()
{
 char *msg = NULL;
 unsigned long x = 0xDEADBEEF;

 msg = f("%X%X%X%X", x, x, x, x);
 if(!msg) return -1;

 puts(msg);

 return 0;
}
```

The function shall return allocated string (char*) containing formatted text. It works correctly on Linux and Windows. It returns badly formatted text on OSX and sometimes it leads to Segmentation fault (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). Btw, I know that I can use vasprintf.

What can be the problem?

Comment: There is lots of extra code there to claim "undefined behavior of vsprintf".

Comment: The debugger is your friend, use it to step though the code line by line to see what happens. Or run your program in it until it crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you're calling vsnprintf with the same va_list multiple times. This doesn't work in some ABIs.

Look up the man page of va_copy. The short version is to do something like this:

```
      va_list c;
      va_copy(c, arg);

      n = VSNPRINTF(out, lout, fmt, c);
      va_end(c);
```

Comment: An alternative to using `va_copy()` (which isn't supported on MSVC), the `va_start()` and `va_end()` calls can be moved to just before/after the `VSNPRINTF()` call.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Right. I keep forgetting that MSVC is still two decades behind. va_copy is C99.